# Can I Connect My Intranet System To Use an LDAP Directory Credentials From The Users Computer As The Login Credential For My Intranet Site?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, active-directory, ldap

My title might sound a little confusing so I here what the situation is. I have an intranet website built for a company, which is hosted on their own VPN. Each user in the company has their own computer at the office which is always logged in to their account via a LDAP directory. Then there is the intranet which is displayed on their browser. What the client wants is a way so that the intranet which is built in PHP can detect whos' computer it is ran on to login then is the intranet as that user. Currently it uses a username and password form to login in a user. So is there a way using PHP to grab say the users LDAP username from their computer so I can compare it the the users in the intranet DB and login in the correct person?

Iv'e never dealt with LDAP so I don't know what capabilities there are with what the client want. Im not asking for the code on how to do it or anything, just if this is possible and what route to take with this. Any input would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you of course you can

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication

Comment: Awesome! thanks for the feed back